# Dynamic QueryDSL Projection

Tags: querydsl

I've been using QueryDSL for a while and lately I'm wondering if it's possible to make dynamic projections using the framework, e.g.:

Let's say I have an entity as follows:

```
public Class User {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int age;
    private String address;
    ...Getters and Setters
}
```

and an endpoint specifying the fields:

```
http://localhost/users/1?fields=id,username,address
```

when one fires a get on that address, the expected result would be an object with the `id, username, and address` properties.

I know a couple of ways of projecting queries using QueryDSL but none includes an 'elegant' solution when dealing with dynamic fields.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way (imo) of generating a query from a Request query string is adding *@QuerydslPredicate* to the method signature in the Controller, as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe). This gives you a predicate that'll be used in the repository without any extra boilerplate code.
Regarding the result of that query having only the fields that were specified in the query, that could be a job for the client, so it shows only the same fields that were sent.

Comment: how to do this programmatically? I am using graphql and QuerydslPredicate would probably conflict with my controller.